# Multiplying matrices in a cell array

Tags: matlab

Suppose you have an N x 1 cell array where each constituent cell is an m x m matrix. I would like the matrix product (i.e. not entry-by-entry multiplication) of these matrices, so if E_i is the ith matrix in the cell array. I would like to compute E_1 * E_2 * ... * E_N. Any ideas for a vectorized approach to this?

Answer (score 2):

The most direct way is to do this (where `p` is your answer and `cellarray` is your cell array). `*` is the matrix multiplication while `.*` is the element-by-element multiplication you wish to avoid.

```
p = 1;    
for i = 1:N,
   p = p*cellarray{i};
end
```

Comment: Well, yes, that's good. I should've specified that I was looking for a vectorized method.

Comment: oh! I see now. Hm.. okay. Well, you got me. mtimes requires things to happen in operation and everything is in cell arrays. I'm guessing N isn't fixed either?

Comment: I wouldn't name any MATLAB variable [`prod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/prod.html)!

Comment: @user19192 It could be converted to a one-liner with `cellfun`, but it wont make a difference. This is going to be the best way - and will almost certainly be just-in-time compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be vectorized since the iterations aren't independent of each other. A multiplication at some step is dependent on all the multiplications prior to it.