# Extracting block diagonal from matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an njxnj matrix made up of nxn matrices. I want to extract the diagonal j blocks of nxn matrices. i.e. I want to extract the diagonal (for n = 2, j = 4):

[image]

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To index the elements you can use `blkdiag` to create a corresponding mask.

```
%your parameters
n=2
j=4
%some example matrix
M=magic(n*j);
%create the input for blkdiag, j matrices of size n
h=repmat({true(n)},j,1)
%use blkdiag to select the elements
M(logical(blkdiag(h{:})))
```

Comment: Very good answer! I'd throw in a final `reshape(M(...),n,n,[])`, but obviously that's not very hard to figure out.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Also, if I want to take the product of these diagonal matrices is there anyway to apply the `prod` function to the output of `reshape`?

Comment: @user3701257 if you mean element-wise product, then yes, you can call `prod(newM,3)` if `newM` is your `reshape`d `[n x n x j]` matrix. If you need a matrix product, that's a different issue, and much more difficult (you'll probably need a loop for that).

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes I require the matrix product. So the best way to tackle that would be: `P=eye(n);for k=1:size(newM, 3); P = newM(:,:,k)*P;end`

Comment: @user3701257 not necessarily the best, but a straightforward one, yes.  There are probably [questions about this on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594070/multiplying-matrices-in-a-cell-array), and [I also found a MEX function on the FEX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45650-cumulative-matrix-multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

For large j, this answer of @Daniel becomes slow. I would instead recommend using linear indices of block diagonal.

```
    n=2;
    j=4;
    %some example matrix
    M=magic(n*j);
    linIndices = (0:n*((n*j)+1):n*((n*j)+1)*(j-1))+reshape((1:n)'+n*j*(0:n-1),[],1);
    newM = reshape(M(linIndices),n,n,[]);
```